# Component Re-renders onChangeText

Tags: react-native

I made a custom TextInput that I'm animating into view on my Registration screen component. The issue is that for every keystroke onChangeText, the animation plays again and this is not the expected behavior. If I take out the animation, the TextInput works fine.

I've tried changing my dependency on my useState, also tried to wrap the component with a useCallback and useMemo and none has gotten it to work.

Also worthy of note is that I'm handling my state management with useReducer. Code below

```
const RegistrationScreen = ({ navigation }: any) => {
    const textPosition = new Animated.Value(width);
    const inputPosition = new Animated.Value(width);
    const inputPosition2 = new Animated.Value(width);
    const inputPosition3 = new Animated.Value(width);
    const inputPosition4 = new Animated.Value(width);

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

    const { name, email_address, phone_number, password } = state;

    const animate = Animated.sequence([
        Animated.parallel([
            Animated.timing(textPosition, {
                toValue: 0,
                delay: 50,
                duration: 1000,
                useNativeDriver: true,
                easing: Easing.elastic(3),
            }),
            Animated.timing(inputPosition, {
                toValue: 0,
                delay: 100,
                duration: 1000,
                useNativeDriver: true,
                easing: Easing.elastic(3),
            }),
            Animated.timing(inputPosition2, {
                toValue: 0,
                delay: 200,
                duration: 1000,
                useNativeDriver: true,
                easing: Easing.elastic(3),
            }),
            Animated.timing(inputPosition3, {
                toValue: 0,
                delay: 300,
                duration: 1000,
                useNativeDriver: true,
                easing: Easing.elastic(3),
            }),
            Animated.timing(inputPosition4, {
                toValue: 0,
                delay: 400,
                duration: 1000,
                useNativeDriver: true,
                easing: Easing.elastic(3),
            }),
        ]),
    ]);

    const _onCreateAccountHandler = () => dispatch(getPhoneVerificationCode(phone_number));
    const _onChangeHandler = (field: any, value: any) => dispatch({ type: 'FIELD', field, value });

    useEffect(() => {
        animate.start();
    }, [animate]);

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <KeyboardAvoidingView
                style={{ flex: 1 }}
                keyboardVerticalOffset={100}
                behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}>
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                        <Header
                            backButtonEnabled
                            backButtonColor={colors.darkGray}
                            onBackButtonPress={() => navigation.goBack(null)}
                        />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
                        <Animated.View
                            style={[
                                styles.createAccount,
                                {
                                    transform: [
                                        {
                                            translateX: textPosition,
                                        },
                                    ],
                                },
                            ]}>
                            <Text style={styles.creaetAccountText}>{strings.create_an_account}</Text>
                        </Animated.View>

                        <View style={styles.textAreaContainer}>
                            <Animated.View
                                style={[
                                    styles.textInputContainer,
                                    {
                                        transform: [
                                            {
                                                translateX: inputPosition,
                                            },
                                        ],
                                    },
                                ]}>
                                <TextInput
                                    placeHolder={strings.name}
                                    value={name}
                                    onChangeText={(text: any) => _onChangeHandler('name', text)}
                                    onCancelPressed={() => {}}
                                    placeHolderStyle={{
                                        backgroundColor: colors.lightWhite,
                                    }}
                                    autoCorrect={false}
                                />
                            </Animated.View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping animate with [React.useCallback()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)

Comment: That didn't quite fix it.

Answer (score 0):

So From further research, it turns out that since I'm animating the component with a value that is always constant (width), onTextChange will always rerender the screen and any value that is different will be accounted for, hence, the animation plays again since the current value is different from the initial value.

**My Solution:**
I had to use useState to change the initial value as soon as the first animation completes. I also had to call that in a setTimeout that runs after the animation that way - the initial width will update to become the current width and when the component re-renders, it won't render again. (or in this case, there's no difference in the translate X value, so animation won't play again)